# Privileges should also take into account experience

Tags: discussion, privileges

I ran a rough search on meta and couldn't find this topic.

So recently I received the [Edit Questions And Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege which says:

> *once you've generated enough reputation, we trust you to edit anything in the system without it going through peer review. Not just
>   your posts—anyone's posts!*

I'm on SO for about 3 years and only starting september 2017 I started really answering questions and let me tell you, **getting 2000 rep is easy**.

Thankfully, while answering, I also suggested edits, which they got approved.
I have 33 edit suggestions approved, and 3 edit suggestions rejected (2 of the rejected ones I knew for sure I was right, I resubmitted them and got approved by other more careful reviewers).

So yeah, I feel confident when I edit other posts, because I only do that when I'm sure I'm right.

However, I don't think that's always true. One popular question/answer might boost someone's rep to the point they get this privilege and can wrongfully edit anyone's post.

I believe this privilege should be received under conditions similar to the followings (feel free to propose other values if you feel they are inaccurate):

- yes, **2000 rep** is ok
- but also **at least 10 suggestion edits, with 90% of them approved**.

  - If they have more suggestion edits by the time they get to 2000 rep, that 90% percent should apply to the whole number (you have 100 suggestion edits, max 10 are allowed to be rejected)

This criteria makes it relevant to know if you are indeed entitled to edit anyone's post.

Same thing will apply for [Approve Tag Wiki Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege. I would also take into account the number of tags suggested, approved and in use.

Thoughts?

Comment: I agree with the intention, but the added requirement wouldn't change almost anything, IMO. 10 approved edits are much, much, much easier to get than 2k rep.

Comment: @yivi - correct(ish), but accompanied with 90% *success rate*, it tells us two things: **(1)** they are interested in editing and **(2)** they do that with accuracy

Comment: Might be. Would need to look up some data to see if 90% is a lot or extremely easy to get. No time to dig into SEDE right now. Going by gut, I'd say 90% is easy-peasy.

Comment: At least it'll weed out the truly bad cases?

Comment: Before we had the current review system, reviewers were required to have the "Strunk & White" badge before they could access /review. So there is a precedent.

Comment: 900 rep, 23 edits suggested, 23 approved -> 100%

Comment: @WhatsThePoint - What's the point? That by the time you get 2000 rep you'll totally deserve the privilege? Or that you deserve it, and deserve it NOW?

Comment: I think that the point is that having >90% is all-too-easy. What's the rejection threshold for editing ban? Is it known?

Comment: @Adelin the point was edits are not hard to get

Comment: I don't mean they are hard to get, but as @Cerbrus said, it'll filter out bad cases.

Comment: Hadn’t read that. But yes, exactly that.

Comment: Oh dear...my suggested edit ratio is bad :( _82 edit suggestions approved, and 17 edit suggestions rejected_ .. Although I had quite a few community rejects. Probably needs to be taken into consideration

Comment: @SurajRao sarcasm aside, suggest a new ratio then :)

Comment: @SurajRao yes ... glad you found out, I hesitated to rub it in ...

Comment: I like the *getting 2000 rep is easy* claim and I'm going to (ab)use that for the next meta post from a new user when they state *can't get rep here, halp me*

Comment: @Adelin just pointing out that community rejects due to simultaneous edits is a thing.. On the whole not averse to the idea